# wifi doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04 after a short time until I restart the system

Tags: wireless, restart

*My Situation:*

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new HP laptop.

*My problem:*

My system is able to connect to my wifi router after the system starts, but after few minutes (30-45 min) the internet doesn't work even though the wifi status show as connected. I have executed wireless_script when wifi status is shown as connected but the internet still doesn't work.

Please find the [wireless-info.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10810182)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Apr 2015 23:13 IST +0530

Booted last: 12 Apr 2015 22:53 IST +0530

Script from: 06 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2337]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 14109  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
rtl8723be              85054  0 
btcoexist              50304  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         23361  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                64255  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              652718  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              494362  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19193  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1000  Metric:1
          RX packets:7051 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1940264 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:1229806 (1.2 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Katrina kaif"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-10 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:17   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [Katrina kaif] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    ArpanPrateek:    Infra, <MAC 'ArpanPrateek' [AN1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    mehack:          Infra, <MAC 'mehack' [AN2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA WPA2
    hell:            Infra, <MAC 'hell' [AN3]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    crusaders:       Infra, <MAC 'crusaders' [AN4]>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    PrAneesh:        Infra, <MAC 'PrAneesh' [AN5]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2
    andhra4infy:     Infra, <MAC 'andhra4infy' [AN6]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    *Katrina kaif:   Infra, <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 46 WPA WPA2
    Rockstar:        Infra, <MAC 'Rockstar' [AN8]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/odiyatoka]] (600 root)
[connection] id=odiyatoka | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=odiyatoka | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XT1068 3606]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XT1068 3606 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=XT1068 3606 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Katrina kaif]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Katrina kaif | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Katrina kaif | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]> | mtu=1000
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AIRTEL_E5172_170C]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AIRTEL_E5172_170C | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AIRTEL_E5172_170C | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C94095C986767A931B924EF
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7410431A59C24B1BC33226E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     3273ECD6028617EFD27E4F4
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     5410C94462FA26A0A3F256C
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     4A525D9D32B0C6D120CA547
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        25:26:EE:FE:32:C9:58:B4:CD:85:CA:5F:BF:EB:ED:A1:75:D1:B2:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf]
options ath5k nohwcrypt

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   11.682997] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   11.683225] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   16.023693] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.024236] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]>
[   17.034441] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   17.037434] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.042932] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   17.046764] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Katrina kaif' [AN7]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=6)
[   17.046977] wlan0: associated
[   17.046984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/608423/edit) your question to include the output. This will help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Team,

Please find the detailed decription as you asked:

My Situation : I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new HP laptop.

My problem : My system is able to connect my wifi after system starts. But after few minutes (30-45) min internet doesn't works even though wifi status show as connected. I have executed wireless_script when wifi status shown as connected but internet doesn't work.

Please find the wireless-info.txt :http://paste.ubuntu.com/10810182/


Thanks & Regards,
Jagadish

Comment: Please let me know soon . I am struggling here.

Comment: What is the model of the HP laptop?

Comment: My laptop model no. is HP 15-R203TX Notebook

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is outdated please see Pilot6 answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675581/wifi-problem-with-hp-probook)

First try

```
$ echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot and if it still has issues follow instructions below to install backports

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
$ wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
$ tar -xf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.xz
$ cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1
$ make defconfig-rtlwifi
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Reboot the system.

**Note**

The only issue with backports is that they need to be built for any new kernel that gets installed with updates, when that happens you

```
$ cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1
$ make clean
$ make defconfig-rtlwifi
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

You may also want to check the wifi router encryptions settings to see if they are **WPA2-AES** or **WPA2** only as it would be prefered.

**Edit (Support for other kernel driver of wireless)**

In above, we add a backport support for `rtlwifi` driver which HP laptop's   Wireless/Network card have. Other laptop manufacturer provide other provider Wirless card, so for that first you have to find the name of kernel driver your wireless card support, you can get that by simply run `lspci` command in a shell, go to `Network Controller` and see the last line of it.

```
$ lspci -v
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
        Memory at f1b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

In mine laptop, i have `iwlwifi` named kernel driver of network card.
So for that commands are as follows:-

```
$ cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1
$ make clean
$ make defconfig-iwlwifi
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: thnx :). It solved my problem .

Comment: Will you accept the answer so other people might see that it works?