# WiFi problem with hp probook

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I have a hp probook 470 G2 on which I have Windows and Ubuntu installed.
 WiFi works on Windows but not on Ubuntu. At start up I get this message :

```
rtlwifi: Firmware rtlwifirtl8723befw.bin not available.
```

Could you please help me fix this problem?

The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is :

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. And please specify the Ubuntu version.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: it is ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You could not install the driver from my ppa, because I did not make it for 12.04. It is available there for 14.04 and 15.04. Why did not you install 14.04? It is possible to install a driver for 12.04, but I did not test it.

Comment: I am more comfortable with ubuntu 12.04, and also i am using pytthon 2.7 and don't want to use python 3 because most all my codes don't work with. Is there no way to activate the wifi for 12.04?

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -r`?

Comment: kernel version : 3.13.0-32-generic

Comment: And you can use python 2.7 in 14.04. Python 3 is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

and reboot.

Comment: I have runned the commands and my wifi is back. Thanks a lot